# Accept a sentence and print the words that have consecutive characters in them

Tags: java, string, character

Accept a sentence and print the words that have consecutive characters in them

INPUT: hi my dog is naughty

OUTPUT: hi naughty

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program6  {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Sentence : ");
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        s=s.toLowerCase();
        int l= s.length();
        s=' '+s+' ';
        int i;char c,d;int a,b,j=0; 
        for (i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            c=s.charAt(i);
            d=s.charAt(i+1);
            a=c;
            b=d;
            if(d==' ')
             j=i;
            if((a+1)==b)
             System.out.println(s.substring(0,j));
            }
    }
}
```

It shows class compiled-no syntax error but the output is not coming properly, it is showing something different.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out
after converting the string to lower case-

```
    s=s+" ";
    l=s.length();
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        ch=s.charAt(i);
        if(ch!=' ')
        w=w+ch;
        else
        {
            word=w;
            w="";
            for(j=0;j<word.length()-1;j++)
            {
                c=word.charAt(j);
                d=word.charAt(j+1);
                if(d==c+1)
                System.out.print(word+"  ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues in your code like, In your code, even if you find that two consecutive characters in a word are neighbor of each other, you try to do substring and may be you never setter j because you never found a space before and hence you pass 0,0 as parameter to substring method.

Easier way would be:

1. Split the sentence by one or more space
2. Check for consecutive characters whether two consecutive characters are neighbors to each other.
3. If they are then print that word and then move to next word if any
4. if not then move to other character.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import java.util.*;
public class Ch8_30
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     Scanner x= new Scanner(System.in);
     String s;int i=0,b=0,a=0,c=0;
     System.out.println("enter a string");
     s=x.nextLine().toUpperCase();
     String m[]=s.split("\\s");
     for(i=0;i<m.length;i++)
     {
         b=0;
         for(a=0;a<m[i].length();a++)
         {
             if(a==m[i].length()-1)
             break;

             if((char)(m[i].charAt(a)+1)==m[i].charAt(a+1))
             {
                 b++;c++;
                 System.out.println(m[i]);
                 break;
             }

         }     
     }
     System.out.println("no. of words "+c);
    }
}
```